# Cross-domain phonegap proxy hangs forever on POST

Tags: cordova

I am building an app using PhoneGap and AngularJS.

I have run into the issue that when I submit a POST request to my server that the request hangs forever.  However, when I am running the server on localhost on a different port, everything works as expected, in fact phonegap does not even attempt to use the localhost:3000/proxy

I've been looking at this for some time and cannot seem to figure out what the problem is, although I have noticed a few strange things.

The request is not treated as an XHR (it doesn't show as an XHR when filtered in debug tools), also, the method header is not being set, but it is showing as a "POST" in the Network log in Chrome Dev Tools.

Here is a successful GET request from Chrome:

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:3000
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/proxy/http%3A%2F%xxx.azurewebsites.net%2Fapi%2Flocation%2Fnearby%3Flat%3D33.8686264%26lng%3D-118.3725046
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId=euvpej4dpiv1ukmxl0t23xac; FedAuth=77u/PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiP....; connect.sid=s%3Aylq57xG3DkRfuNql0vtPgYWH.AgKDiQqMzswmwe1jat1CIme38V0bmecwIbdNj6O8DQ0; _gat=1; _ga=GA1.1.2047046828.1409352860
Host:localhost:3000
Referer:http://localhost:3000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36
Response Headersview source
cache-control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
content-encoding:gzip
content-length:584
content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8
date:Mon, 13 Oct 2014 01:03:55 GMT
expires:-1
pragma:no-cache
server:Microsoft-IIS/8.0
set-cookie:ARRAffinity=dc683772935cbd7c69ab3a4b248dc744da819f1d1ec4860117f383527d8e64a7;Path=/;Domain=xxx.azurewebsites.net
vary:Accept-Encoding
x-aspnet-version:4.0.30319
x-powered-by:ASP.NET
```

Here is the post request that continues to hang forever on "PENDING".  I notice that there is no Request Method, and that the content-type has charset=utf-8 appended to it for some inexplicable reason.  **Is there any way to disable the proxy all together so that I can just do a standard CORS request?**

```
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/proxy/http%3A%2F%2Fxxx.azurewebsites.net%2Fapi%2Fobservations%2Fcreate%3FapiKey%3Dy4hf9bmesrht3fy9fttf5c4y7maqwmq47
Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Origin:http://localhost:3000
Referer:http://localhost:3000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36
X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id:567F5745-35A5-460C-B08B-817C30F388CB
Request Payloadview source
{altitude:, date:2014-10-13, hasSpecimen:false, notes:,…}
altitude: ""
confidence: "1.0"
date: "2014-10-13"
hasSpecimen: false
latitude: 33.8686264
location: "Manhattan Beach, California, USA, , "
longitude: -118.3725046
name: ""
notes: ""
vote: ""
```

Comment: Again, this all works fine when I am on localhost as the phonegap proxy (which I assume is just node.js) isn't invoked.

Comment: It appears that there is something wrong with the nodeJS/phonegap/cordova proxy. If I change the controller to accept URI parameters on my server, everything works fine.  But, any sort of payload attached to the POST request causes it time out after 5 minutes.